# Get FB like and share for each country of any page with permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to use this code to get total fans for my page :

```
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. 'fql?q=SELECT object_id, metric, value, end_time
                   FROM insights
                   WHERE object_id  = [139832966167942]
                        AND metric IN (\'page_fans\')
                        AND period = period(\'lifetime\')
                        AND end_time = end_time_date(\'2014-3-31\')'
                       . '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```

but all the time is gives : Warning: file_get_contents : failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here... The link_stat table is mostly used for external pages which are using FB functionality like the "like button" etc. The per country stats are only available via insights imho...

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear enough. I am getting total counts with my code what i want is separate like count for every country and share count also.

Comment: As I wrote, you can't get country info from link_stat